# I want jquery popup should come once the form is submitted using php and mysql, the output has come in jquery popup

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, popup

I want  jquery popup should come once the form is submitted using php and mysql, the output has come in jquery popup?I have fetched the values from table.Those value I have to show in pop?what kind of pop is available for that?

This is the value I want to show in popup?once the form is submitted.Those values are from db?

Here is the db values:

```
id  Author Names                 Title of the Paper       Journal                Vol              Yr    Pages
1   V.Thahira Banu Assistant     Semantic Sensor Network  A Survey International Special Volume   2013 p.no:549 to 553      
    Professor, PSGR Krishna..
2   .......................
3   .......................
```

Comment: It's extremely difficult to understand what you want, also some code of what you've already tried and how your form looks would help a lot to help you!

Comment: I want the database values shown in popup once the form is submitted?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery by itself has no UI elements. You either have to use the traditional javascript alert() or include a UI library like jQueryUI and use their [dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/) component or equivalent.

Comment: Ok I understood,This is the code I have written once form is submitted mysql_query("SELECT e.*,year.yearname FROM $ename e left join useradd u on  e.user_id=u.id
  left join year on year.year_id=e.ayear where e.ayear=$yname") values are coming, I want to show those values in jquery popup

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript Alert or a plugin for that.

```
JavaScript Alert

Alert(data);
```

of visit this link [Sample Alert Plugins](http://www.freshdesignweb.com/jquery-notification-plugin-example.html) for use of plugins

Comment: I know how to include jquery plugin and css, I have doubt, will the jquery code automatically call the class  id or class to popup  the database value, because each and every time we will call the function we do onclick(),now the values are coming from db, how do we call the function

Comment: @user3251820 are you using Ajax and JQuery for submitting the form values?

Comment: no I am using php and mysql It has load and come back to open the dialog

Comment: @user3251820 I know that, you can use JQuery and Ajax to submit the form values to the PHP Script at the server which in turn connect to the database

Answer (score 0):

This is the best thing, you should use and try :- http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Answer (score 0):

Check the code:

Index.php

```
<?php
require_once"class/db.php";
$db= new db();
$data=$db->fetch_user_det();
?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Dialog - Animation</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery- ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
autoOpen: false,
show: {
effect: "blind",
duration: 1000
},
hide: {
effect: "explode",
duration: 1000
}
});
$( "#opener" ).click(function() {
$( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
<p>
<table width="200" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td>Name</td>
<td>Class</td>
<td>Roll</td>
</tr> 
<?php
foreach($data as $val)
{
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $val['field_name1']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $val['field_name2']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $val['field_name3']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?></table>
</p>
</div>
<button id="opener">Open Dialog</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Database Class:  db.php

you can download full project from here: http://1drv.ms/OzfdH4

just edit database details in db.php

check updated link